# Unity 4.6 UI button AddListener sets the same callback to all items in List

Tags: c#, unity, gui

I have this method that is looping through a list and sets values on the current item in the list. Everything works fine the lists values are correct exept the AddListener. All listeners on the elements are the exact same as the last element! I have no clue where to go from here. Why is all values working exept the callback? Can anyone explain this to me please.
Thanks in advance

```
void PopulateList() {
        foreach (var item in itemList) {
            GameObject newButton = Instantiate(sampleButton) as GameObject;
            SampleButton button = newButton.GetComponent<SampleButton>();
            button.playerLabel.text = item.PlayerName;
            button.opponentLabel.text = item.opponentName;
            //sampleButton.myTurn.SetActive(item.MyTurn);
            button.myTurn = item.MyTurn;
            button.button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
            button.button.onClick.AddListener(() => test(item.callbackText)); // item.callbackText is just a a string
            button.playerTurnLabel.text = item.PlayerTurnText;
            newButton.transform.SetParent (contentPanel); // sets parent of button
        }
    }

void test(string whatever) {
        Debug.Log(whatever);
    }

public class SampleButton : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button button;
    public Text playerLabel;
    public Text playerPoints;
    public Text opponentLabel;
    public Text opponentPoints;
    public bool myTurn;
    public Text playerTurnLabel;

}
```

Comment: I had a problem with using list items in a lambda like this. Try making a temporary item reference before you make the lambda and use that instead. EDIT: Like this: Item tempItem = item; buttton.button.onClick.AddListener( () => test( tempItem.callbackText ) );

Comment: I see. It worked like a charm :) it just didnt accour to me that temp references had such importance. I learned a hard lession now. If you write and answer I will gladly verify it as OK. And thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a temporary reference:

```
Item tempItem = item;
button.button.onClick.AddListener( () => test( tempItem.callbackText ) );
```

For some reason lambdas like this don't work too well when accessing list elements through either index or iterator. It might have to do with how the lambda captures the variable.